# magento fallback not working

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have set up new 1.9.3 magento. I have a css files present in default/default folder. It does not present in custom_package/custom_theme and custom_package/default_theme. It is going directly to the base/default. It should check in default/default. is there any way to achieve the proper fallback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a Fallback by set up `etc/theme.xml` for each theme like below:

1. In `custom_package/custom_theme/etc/theme.xml` file set as:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <theme>
     <parent>custom_package/default_theme</parent>
   </theme>
   ```
2. In `custom_package/default_theme/etc/theme.xml` file set as:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <theme>
      <parent>default/default</parent>
   </theme>
   ```
3. In `default/default/etc/theme.xml` file set as:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <theme>
      <parent>base/default</parent>
   </theme>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

default/default is a remnant from pre 1.4 magento and is only there for backwards compatibility on older modules, it will fall back to base default and ignore default default, unless you specifically tell it otherwise. In short, base/default is the new default/default

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30592/why-is-there-a-base-default-layout-and-a-default-default-layout